# Batch Long Code Multi Line Caret

Tags: batch-file

I have a script written in Batch code. Basically the code is to copy all .htm in a folder to another folder. My problem is that some of the folders are having empty spaces and I need to exclude some of the folders as well. I'm using robocopy to do so.

For eg.

```
@echo off
robocopy.exe ^
Z:\xxx\folder\ ^
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\New ^
*.htm ^
/xd ^
Z:\xxx\folder\abc ^
Z:\xxx\folder\aaa ^
Z:\xxx\folder\bbb ^
"Z:\xxx\folder\problem here" ^
/S
pause
```

I tried with double quotes

```
@echo off
robocopy.exe ^
Z:\xxx\folder\ ^
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\New ^
*.htm ^
/xd ^
Z:\xxx\folder\abc ^
Z:\xxx\folder\aaa ^
Z:\xxx\folder\bbb ^
Z:\xxx\folder\problem here ^
/S
pause
```

And it's not working. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spend it a space in front of each line:

```
@echo ON
robocopy.exe ^
 "Z:\xxx\folder\" ^
 "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\New" ^
 "*.htm" ^
 /xd ^
 "Z:\xxx\folder\abc" ^
 "Z:\xxx\folder\aaa" ^
 "Z:\xxx\folder\bbb" ^
 "Z:\xxx\folder\problem here" ^
 /S
pause
```

(with `echo on` the command line is repeated as it will be executed, so you can easily check, if it's ok)

Comment: Oh as simple as that! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Directories with spaces needs escaping. Also look at your slashes and consider using `/MIR` option.

```
robocopy 
 "Z:\xxx\folder\" ^
 "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\New\" ^
 "*.htm" ^
 /MIR ^
 /XD ^
 "Z:\xxx\folder\abc" ^
 "Z:\xxx\folder\aaa" ^
 "Z:\xxx\folder\bbb" ^
 "Z:\xxx\folder\problem here" ^
 /S
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

(Like [@Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49002325/463115) already wrote) You need one space before your quoted string `"Z:\xxx\folder\problem here" ^`.
The cause is a nasty behaviour of the caret `^` when used for line continuation.
When the caret is the last character in a line it will append the next line, **but also escapes the first character of that line**.
In your case the first quote will be escaped, therefore the second quote will be used to enable quoting for the rest of the line (also the last caret) and the command ends there.

As Stephan shows it can be avoided by prefix (at least) the quoted lines with a space.

There is also another more obscure way to disable the escaping behaviour by using a dummy redirection just before the caret.

```
robocopy.exe ^
Z:\folder\ <NUL ^
"Z:\folder\problem here" ^
/S
```